# My longtable is not fitting in the pagewidth

Tags: longtable

It looks like this question has been asked many times, but I was unable to solve my problem as I am new to latex.

I have the following longtable in my .tex document

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{AU Number} & \textbf{FACS Name} & \textbf{Muscular Basis}\\
\midrule
0   &   face    &       \\
1   &   Inner Brow Raiser   &   frontalis (pars medialis)   \\
2   &   Outer Brow Raiser   &   frontalis (pars lateralis)  \\
4   &   Brow Lowerer    &   depressor glabellae, depressor supercilii, corrugator supercilii    \\
5   &   Upper Lid Raiser    &   levator palpebrae superioris, superior tarsal muscle    \\
6   &   Cheek Raiser    &   orbicularis oculi (pars orbitalis)  \\
7   &   Lid Tightener   &   orbicularis oculi (pars palpebralis)    \\
8   &   Lips Toward Each Other  &   orbicularis oris    \\
9   &   Nose Wrinkler   &   levator labii superioris alaeque nasi   \\
10  &   Upper Lip Raiser    &   levator labii superioris, caput infraorbitalis  \\
11  &   Nasolabial Deepener &   zygomaticus minor   \\
12  &   Lip Corner Puller   &   zygomaticus major   \\
13  &   Sharp Lip Puller    &   levator anguli oris (also known as caninus) \\
14  &   Dimpler &   buccinator  \\
15  &   Lip Corner Depressor    &   depressor anguli oris (also known as triangularis)  \\
16  &   Lower Lip Depressor &   depressor labii inferioris  \\
17  &   Chin Raiser &   mentalis    \\
18  &   Lip Pucker  &   incisivii labii superioris and incisivii labii inferioris   \\
19  &   Tongue Show &       \\
20  &   Lip Stretcher   &   risorius w/ platysma    \\
21  &   Neck Tightener  &   platysma    \\
22  &   Lip Funneler    &   orbicularis oris    \\
23  &   Lip Tightener   &   orbicularis oris    \\
24  &   Lip Pressor &   orbicularis oris    \\
25  &   Lips Part   &   depressor labii inferioris, or relaxation of mentalis or orbicularis oris   \\
26  &   Jaw Drop    &   masseter; relaxed temporalis and internal pterygoid \\
27  &   Mouth Stretch   &   pterygoids, digastric   \\
28  &   Lip Suck    &   orbicularis oris    \\
29  &   Jaw Thrust  &       \\
30  &   Jaw Sideways    &       \\
31  &   Jaw Clencher    &   masseter    \\
32  &   [Lip] Bite  &       \\
33  &   [Cheek] Blow    &       \\
34  &   [Cheek] Puff    &       \\
35  &   [Cheek] Suck    &       \\
36  &   [Tongue] Bulge  &       \\
37  &   Lip Wipe    &       \\
38  &   Nostril Dilator &   nasalis (pars alaris)   \\
39  &   Nostril Compressor  &   nasalis (pars transversa) and depressor septi nasi  \\
41  &   Glabella Lowerer    &   Separate Strand of AU 4: depressor glabellae (aka procerus) \\
42  &   Inner Eyebrow Lowerer   &   Separate Strand of AU 4: depressor supercilii   \\
43  &   Eyes Closed &   Relaxation of levator palpebrae superioris  \\
44  &   Eyebrow Gatherer    &   Separate Strand of AU 4: corrugator supercilli  \\
45  &   Blink   &   Relaxation of levator palpebrae superioris; contraction of orbicularis oculi (pars palpebralis) \\
46  &   Wink    &   orbicularis oculi   \\

\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

I just want to make sure so that the text in the column Muscular Basis, does not go outside my page margins. Each line of text under the Muscular Basis column can be in multiple lines but in the same row.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by defining column specifier for the last column by `\newcolumntype` command with one argument for column width, as shown below.

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

the `m{#1}` means paragraph column with text vertically aligned in the middle (requires `array` package)

one can decide the last column width by saying `C{7cm}` for example to prvent hitting the page margin.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} 
\begin{longtable}{@{}llC{7cm}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{AU Number} & \textbf{FACS Name} & \textbf{Muscular Basis}\\
\midrule
0   &   face    &       \\
1   &   Inner Brow Raiser   &   frontalis (pars medialis)   \\
2   &   Outer Brow Raiser   &   frontalis (pars lateralis)  \\
4   &   Brow Lowerer    &   depressor glabellae, depressor supercilii, corrugator supercilii    \\
5   &   Upper Lid Raiser    &   levator palpebrae superioris, superior tarsal muscle    \\
6   &   Cheek Raiser    &   orbicularis oculi (pars orbitalis)  \\
7   &   Lid Tightener   &   orbicularis oculi (pars palpebralis)    \\
8   &   Lips Toward Each Other  &   orbicularis oris    \\
9   &   Nose Wrinkler   &   levator labii superioris alaeque nasi   \\
10  &   Upper Lip Raiser    &   levator labii superioris, caput infraorbitalis  \\
11  &   Nasolabial Deepener &   zygomaticus minor   \\
12  &   Lip Corner Puller   &   zygomaticus major   \\
13  &   Sharp Lip Puller    &   levator anguli oris (also known as caninus) \\
14  &   Dimpler &   buccinator  \\
15  &   Lip Corner Depressor    &   depressor anguli oris (also known as triangularis)  \\
16  &   Lower Lip Depressor &   depressor labii inferioris  \\
17  &   Chin Raiser &   mentalis    \\
18  &   Lip Pucker  &   incisivii labii superioris and incisivii labii inferioris   \\
19  &   Tongue Show &       \\
20  &   Lip Stretcher   &   risorius w/ platysma    \\
21  &   Neck Tightener  &   platysma    \\
22  &   Lip Funneler    &   orbicularis oris    \\
23  &   Lip Tightener   &   orbicularis oris    \\
24  &   Lip Pressor &   orbicularis oris    \\
25  &   Lips Part   &   depressor labii inferioris, or relaxation of mentalis or orbicularis oris   \\
26  &   Jaw Drop    &   masseter; relaxed temporalis and internal pterygoid \\
27  &   Mouth Stretch   &   pterygoids, digastric   \\
28  &   Lip Suck    &   orbicularis oris    \\
29  &   Jaw Thrust  &       \\
30  &   Jaw Sideways    &       \\
31  &   Jaw Clencher    &   masseter    \\
32  &   [Lip] Bite  &       \\
33  &   [Cheek] Blow    &       \\
34  &   [Cheek] Puff    &       \\
35  &   [Cheek] Suck    &       \\
36  &   [Tongue] Bulge  &       \\
37  &   Lip Wipe    &       \\
38  &   Nostril Dilator &   nasalis (pars alaris)   \\
39  &   Nostril Compressor  &   nasalis (pars transversa) and depressor septi nasi  \\
41  &   Glabella Lowerer    &   Separate Strand of AU 4: depressor glabellae (aka procerus) \\
42  &   Inner Eyebrow Lowerer   &   Separate Strand of AU 4: depressor supercilii   \\
43  &   Eyes Closed &   Relaxation of levator palpebrae superioris  \\
44  &   Eyebrow Gatherer    &   Separate Strand of AU 4: corrugator supercilli  \\
45  &   Blink   &   Relaxation of levator palpebrae superioris; contraction of orbicularis oculi (pars palpebralis) \\
46  &   Wink    &   orbicularis oculi   \\

\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```