# Longtable with lscape that really fits page

Tags: longtable, lscape

I have rather large tables, one of them so large that I need to rotate it. 
So I tried a `longtable` inside of the `lscape` environment. 
Now, I have the problem that only some of the columns fit on the page, and the rest just disappear. 
Also, when there are more rows, the table goes over the margin on the right visualized by `\showframe`. The table in my minimal example is not long enough because I didn't want to post such a long table, but you can just copy the content several times.

```
 \documentclass[
%, draft
, 12pt
, a4paper
, english
, numbers=noenddot
, bibliography=totoc
, xcolor=dvipsnames
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}
\newgeometry{bottom=55pt} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\subsection{Uebersicht}


\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable} {|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\toprule
\bfseries Abbreviation from Table 1 & Construct & Measure & English Version (Reference){[}OV = original version, OT=official translation, IT=inofficial translation{]} & German Version (Reference){[}OV = original version, OT=official translation, IT=inofficial translation, OV = items / scales developed forstudy{]} & \hspace{0pt}Number of items & \hspace{0pt}Remarks \\ 
\hline 
\endhead
\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{continued on the next page...} \\
\endfoot


%\\ \hline
\endlastfoot


    \multicolumn{7}{p{16cm}}{\bfseries Well-being}\\
    \hline
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 &  \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 &  \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 &  \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 &  \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 &  \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 &  \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 &  \\
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}


\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I need a general example, not one where I have to change every single column, as I will be using this table many times.

Comment: Even the table head is much to wide. You need, e.g., `p`-columns instead of `c`-columns to place all the text after `English Version` and after `German Version`.

Comment: If I use p instead of c, I get many errors and the document looks completely messed up... So I figured I couldn't use that...

Comment: Then you have done something wrong with the `p`-columns and you should have shown, what you have done. They do work. See my answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My longtable is not fitting in the pagewidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167732/my-longtable-is-not-fitting-in-the-pagewidth) or [Longtable doesn't fit page size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294050/longtable-doesnt-fit-page-size).

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks are only available in `p`-columns (and derived column types). So you cannot use `c`-columns for columns, that need line breaks. The `p`-column declaration has one argument: The width of the column. A `p`-column is something like a `\parbox`. So by default the text in the column in justified. But using package [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) you can change the default adding `>{\raggedright}`, `>{\centering}` or `>{\raggedleft}` bevor the column declaration to have left aligned, centered or right aligned columns with automatic (or manual) line breaks. But note, that this would also change `\\` to be a line break instead of a tabular row end. See `\arraybackslash` in the [`array` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) so learn how to fix this. An alternative to `\raggedright`, `\centering` and `\raggedleft` would be to use package [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)'s `\RaggedRight`, `\Centering` or `\RaggedLeft`. These not only allow hyphenation but also avoids the `\\`-problem.

```
\documentclass[
%, draft
, 12pt
, a4paper
, english
, numbers=noenddot
, bibliography=totoc
, xcolor=dvipsnames
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{pdflscape}% show it readable
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{scrhack}% without showframe shows the wrong frame on landscape pages


\begin{document}
\newgeometry{bottom=55pt} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\subsection{Uebersicht}


\begin{landscape}
%\begin{longtable} {*5{>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr ((\linewidth-4.5em)/6)-2\tabcolsep\relax}}>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr 4.5em-2\tabcolsep}>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr ((\linewidth-4.5em)/6)-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
\begin{longtable} {|*5{>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr
  ((\linewidth-4.5em)/6)-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr 4.5em-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr ((\linewidth-4.5em)/6)-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
\toprule
\bfseries Abbreviation from Table 1 & Construct & Measure & English Version (Reference)\par\footnotesize{[}OV = original version,\par OT=official translation,\par IT=inofficial translation{]} & German Version (Reference)\par\footnotesize{[}OV = original version,\par OT=official translation,\par IT=inofficial translation,\par OV = items / scales developed forstudy{]} & Number of items & Remarks \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{continued on the next page...} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bfseries Well-being}\\
\midrule
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this example I've used `\dimexpr` to calculate the maximum width for the columns (and each the same). Each column starts with a white space of width `\tabcolsep` and ends with a white space of `\tabcolsep` plus the width of the vertical rule `\arrayrulewidth`. So the calculation of the column width is easy, if almost all columns should have the same width. To show you how to set an individual width, I've used a different width for the 6th column. As you should know `*5{…}` means: *repeat 5 times declaration {…}*.

But I would recommend to avoid the vertical rules in tables, i.e., if you are using `booktabs`. That would be the version with activates `%`-line and commented second `\begin{longtable}`:

[image]

Note: That the result of `showframe` package is wrong on `landscape` pages of package `lscape` or `pdflscape`. Package `scrhack` fixes this issue (and several other issues).

And maybe something with only centered (but bold) heads would be better:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{pdflscape}% show it readable
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{scrhack}% without showframe shows the wrong frame on landscape pages


\begin{document}
\newgeometry{bottom=55pt} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\subsection{Uebersicht}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable} {*5{>{\RaggedRight}p{\dimexpr
  ((\linewidth-4.5em)/6)-2\tabcolsep\relax}}>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr 4.5em-2\tabcolsep}>{\RaggedRight}p{\dimexpr ((\linewidth-4.5em)/6)-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
%\begin{longtable} {|*5{>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr
%  ((\linewidth-4.5em)/6)-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr 4.5em-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr ((\linewidth-4.5em)/6)-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
\toprule
\bfseries\Centering Abbreviation from Table 1 & 
\bfseries\Centering Construct &
\bfseries\Centering Measure & 
\Centering \textbf{English Version (Reference)}\par \footnotesize{[}OV = original
    version,\par OT=official translation,\par IT=inofficial translation{]} & 
\Centering \textbf{German Version (Reference)}\par\footnotesize{[}OV = original version,\par OT=official translation,\par IT=inofficial translation,\par OV = items / scales developed forstudy{]} &
\bfseries\Centering Number of items & 
\bfseries\Centering Remarks \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{continued on the next page...} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bfseries Well-being}\\
\midrule
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  some dummy text that allows hyphenation &
  20 & \\
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works better than anything I have tried so far, but there are still a few issues: it would be great if the column width would adjust to the amount of text it contains, in order for columns with more text to be wider; or if there was a way to adjust this manually. Also, I need the vertical lines because there is a din standard that says that they should be there, but soemtimes, they just stop before reaching the bottom line of the table. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: @LizzAlice You can adjust the with of each column with the argument of the `p`-column identifier. See any introduction to LaTeX and, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223856/how-to-adjust-alignment-and-column-width-tabular. If you have only some columns with contents that should have line breaks, use `p`-columns only for those. If you need framed table cells, don't use `booktabs`. It wouldn't make sense. But such tables are ugly and often hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you want cells to wrap text, don't use the standard `l,r` or `c` specifiers, and if you want the table to fit page, use `tabularx`. For long tables, the `ltablex` package brings the functionalities of  `longtable` to `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass[
%, draft
, 12pt
, a4paper
, english
, numbers=noenddot
, bibliography=totoc
, xcolor=dvipsnames
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{longtable, ltablex}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{bottom=55pt}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\subsection{Uebersicht}


\begin{landscape}
\keepXColumns
\renewcommand\aboverulesep{0pt}
\renewcommand\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} {|*{7}{ >{\RaggedRight\small\arraybackslash}X|}}
\toprule
\bfseries Abbreviation from Table 1 & Construct & Measure & English Version (Reference){[}OV = original version, OT=official translation, IT=inofficial translation{]} & German Version (Reference){[}OV = original version, OT=official translation, IT=inofficial translation, OV = items / scales developed forstudy{]} & \hspace{0pt}Number of items & \hspace{0pt}Remarks \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{continued on the next page...} \\
\endfoot
%\\ \hline
\endlastfoot
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\bfseries Well-being}\\
    \hline
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 & \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 & \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 & \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 & \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 & \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 & \\
    aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & 20 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution has the same issues as the one above: it would be great if the column width would adjust to the amount of text it contains, in order for columns with more text to be wider; or if there was a way to adjust this manually. Also, I need the vertical lines because there is a din standard that says that they should be there, but soemtimes, they just stop before reaching the bottom line of the table. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: Concerning the 2nd point, the vertical lines, I didn't notice it because of `showframe`. I've fixed it (it was due to the `,\\` before `\hline` is the description of `\endfoot`. For the 1st point, it would be easier to explain how to change the width of `X` columns from a real example. The present texts  are all the same.